# SOQL returns no results when it should (:tempVar1)

Tags: soql, query, salesforce-id, string

When I run this query in my trigger (and similar on Workbench)

```
    Integer number_cdl = [SELECT count() FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE ContentDocumentId = '0698c00000ArHhsAAF'];
```

I get two records as a result.

```
number_cdl = 2
```

Great!

But when I substitude the hardcoded ID with a variable I do not get the same.

```
    System.debug('Filter by this ContentDocument ID: '+cd.Id);
    Integer number_cdl = [SELECT count() FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE ContentDocumentId = :cd.Id];  
    System.debug('# of cdl: '+number_cdl);
```

Debug

```
14:05:23:007 USER_DEBUG [7]|DEBUG|Filter by this ContentDocument ID: 0698c00000ArHhsAAF
14:05:23:008 SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN [8]|Aggregations:0|SELECT COUNT() FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE ContentDocumentId = :tmpVar1
14:05:23:031 USER_DEBUG [10]|DEBUG|# of cdl: 0
```

SOQL in Workbench

```
SELECT LinkedEntityId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE ContentDocumentId = '0698c00000ArHhsAAF'
```

Return 2 records.

If a convert the ID to String, I still get the same result:

```
    String sInteger = String.valueOf(cd.Id);
    System.debug(sInteger);
    Integer number_cdl = [SELECT count() FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE ContentDocumentId = :sInteger];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The Id values you list for the two cases are different `0698c00000ArHh4AAF` vs `0698c00000ArHhsAAF` so that is likely the problem here.

Comment: My mistake I updated the questions with the same ID: 0698c00000ArHhsAAF. I still get the same error.

Comment: Run both versions one after the other in the same environment (to eliminate e.g. sharing and profiles) and they will return the same results.